# How do I curve a section of a model?

Tags: modeling

so I'm new-ish to Blender and currently practicing by just making some random 3D models of stuff. Today I made a model off of this switch:

[image]

My only problem is the edge of the switch, its curved but how I have my model, I have it straight as shown here with the vertices selected:

[image]

Im trying to bow the edges so that it curves up but I've tried so many things to no success. Any easy way to edit the vertices to curve it up without moving them free-handedly?

Comment: Make the actual part, using the mirror modifier, as if it was in between the positions, then just rotate it.

Comment: Gonna have to get even more basic than that with me. As soon as I went in and tried to make sense of the Mirror modifier it glitched the area. Is there like a extrude cylindrically or something? That would be so good right now. Only reason I haven't used a cylinder on the area is because boolean modifier seems very buggy

Comment: Spin could help you. There's a bit to know about it, turning around the 3D cursor from the view angle, I suggest you try to find a tuto about that. Here's what blender doc says about it : https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/spin.html?highlight=spin

Comment: "bow the edges so that it curves", do you mean bevel?

Comment: rotation of a vertex with proportional editing could help too, you only need to choose a good axis to turn around and handy falloff and radius. https://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/transformations/transform_control/proportional_edit.html

Comment: or use a curve, and use "mesh from curve" (object menu/convert to, or Alt-C). Then join the meshes and remove doubles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done by selecting the bottom two vertices, pressing <kbd>O</kbd>, and moving them in the desired direction (be sure to put it on the *Sharp* falloff type and make the radius large enough using <kbd>Scroll</kbd>):

[image: Proportional Edit]

---

Although you can do this, I would recommend making the switch as if it was in between the two states, so it is symmetrical. You can then easily rotate it.

[image]

Start by forming the switch profile. Add a circle with 12 vertices, and in edit mode select all and press <kbd>S</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd>, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to finish. Now select all except the bottom vertices and delete them.

[image: Prepare curve]

Now you can extrude downwards using <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>. When scale the new vertices to zero along the zed axis by pressing <kbd>S</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd>. Now scale along the Y axis as desired (<kbd>S</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd>).

[image: Form outline]

Now extrude the outline to the desired width using <kbd>E</kbd>.

[image: Switch]

Now you can delete half of the vertices.

[image: Delete verts]

And add a *Mirror Modifier*:

[image: Mirror modifier]

Make sure you select the right *Axis*, either `X`, `Y` or `Z`. In this case it is `Y`.

Now any changes you make to the one half are exactly mirrored to the other half. Also, this piece can be rotated easily to animate the switch if ever necessary.

**Things you might want to consider:**

- Bevel modifier/Sub-Division modifier
- Re-calculate Normals (Edit mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>)

This should get you a good base mesh to work with, from which you can add specific details.