# Adding a conical bevel/fillet to a mesh?

Tags: modeling

Given this mesh: (assume 18mm x 18mm x 12mm approx.)

[image: The model to be formed]

Is it possible to add a conical fillet (rounded bevel) to the vertical corners?

The cone of the fillet would be 1.85mm - 0.7mm from top to bottom.

Any pointers would be gratefully received.

This image below shows what I'm trying to model (I'm only modelling the outside faces, not the interior socket pieces):

[image: SA Row3 keycaps]

Ideally, I'd also like to add a 0.7mm rounded bevel, which you can see running all along the top edge (as you see here)

## Update: Mesh generated by openscad

The mesh shown in Blender:

[image: mesh]

The original geometry was generated as CSG in OpenSCAD

```
// SA Row 3
difference() {
     intersection_for(n = [1 : 4]) {
          rotate([0, 0, n * 90]) {
               translate([24, 0, 0])
                    sphere(r = 33, $fn = 90);
          }
     }
     translate([0,0,46]) sphere(r = 33, $fn = 90);
     translate([-33,-33,-64]) cube(66);
}
```

Just to give a clear indication that all the surfaces are (save for the base,) sections of a sphere. (note `$fn` is the resolution/polycount)

Comment: Might be interesting: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28042/how-to-model-a-keyboard-key

Comment: These are spherical keys, so they need a different modelling style.  The main faces are created with 4 intersecting spheres and then a difference operation with another sphere to create the spherical dip in the top.  That's the easy part.  Filleting the edges is all I need now.  Really appreciate the additional feedback all the same.

Comment: @zeffii - Files are at https://github.com/getclacking/SA-profile-keys-3D-models

Comment: @zeffii - thats correct, conical fillet, radius changes size from 0.7 to 1.2mm from bottom to top.

Comment: @zeffii - you can see it in the photograph, also see here http://www.keycapsdirect.com/pdfs/SAFamily.pdf

Comment: I was wondering if I should be modelling this using Nurbs surfaces instead of going the CGS route...

Comment: The bottom has to be sliced off, but the rest of the faces are spherical chords

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blender doesn't currently (Nov 2015) have a fillet that does variable radii, but you could approach the same effect with the Subdivision surface modifier to some degree. If you guide the geometry the result will look quite good.

My approach would be to Shrink-wrap a *Polysphere* over the exported Object.

[image]

Below:

- On the left is the original import,
- in the middle is a polysphere (a Cube subdivided a few times and then vertices are transformed with a 'To Sphere' operation),
- to the right is the result of a Shrink wrap from the Polysphere onto the Original geometry

[image]

With a bit of experimentation with the [ShrinkWrap modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html) and tweaking of the Polysphere, you could get very close to what is desired. Because Blender isn't a solid modelling CAD program it is bound by the underlying topology with respect to what can be filleted nicely.

Even on this mesh adding a Subdivision Surface modifier produces visually OK results, this probably doesn't meet tolerance requirements.

[image]

Tweak the polysphere (translating up/down mostly) and the offset value, till it approaches acceptable results.

**The ShrinkWrap object's shape is important**

You'll find that being more specific about the geometry of the Shrinkwrap object will help the eventual wrapped geometry. Here i started by making a copy of the 8 extreme vertices of the imported object, and make a Cube using those vertices. Subdivide the sides and *scale extruded* the top inwards.

[image]

Comment: That would work well enough, this is a project only for mocking up key cap designs, so as long as they're rounded at those top corners it will look right.

Comment: I checked the .blend, the rendering still looks sharp, anything I need to tweak?

Comment: Yes! The results are good enough for my use case.  Thank you

Comment: And this is a great approach :)

Answer (score 2):

I can't see the topology of your object but something like that can probably be done simply selecting top/bottom edge circles and 4 side edges, and using bevel command (<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>), eg: scrolling with the mouse wheel to increase subdivisions...

[image]

Comment: Topology on my object is a very dense mesh, the faces are spherical chords (I don't know if that's the correct name for them.) as opposed to cylindrical chords. Not sure if that will make a difference.  The main thing is to change the radius of the side bevel as it goes from top to bottom.

Comment: Oh also the top is concave, not flat.

Comment: I'll post a wireframe render soon

Comment: Wireframe / Mesh view added to question.  I'll add the csg for reference